# StrToSet by list of members

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a correct MDX query:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[IssueOpened] } ON COLUMNS,
       {(  STRTOSET("[Assigned To].[Id].[Some]:[Assigned To].[Id].[Another]") * 
         [Priorities].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS
FROM (SELECT (STRTOSET("[CreatedOn].[Date].&[2005-01-01T00:00:00]:[CreatedOn].[Date].&[2011-12-01T00:00:00]") ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM [Reports])
```

I need to define a list of attributes (not range) so I modified the query like this:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[IssueOpened] } ON COLUMNS,
       {(  STRTOSET("[Assigned To].[Id].[Some], [Assigned To].[Id].[Another]") * 
         [Priorities].[Id].[Id].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS
FROM (SELECT (STRTOSET("[CreatedOn].[Date].&[2005-01-01T00:00:00]:[CreatedOn].[Date].&[2011-12-01T00:00:00]") ) ON COLUMNS
     FROM [Reports])
```

I have changed

```
STRTOSET("[Assigned To].[Id].[Some]:[Assigned To].[Id].[Another]")
```

to:

```
STRTOSET("[Assigned To].[Id].[Some], [Assigned To].[Id].[Another]")
```

But last query returns error. How can I define a list of attributes in query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add {}.

```
STRTOSET("{[Assigned To].[Id].[Some], [Assigned To].[Id].[Another]}")
```